# Duplicate MongoDB Records Issue with update_one and upsert under High Traffic

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, pymongo

I am currently facing a challenging issue in my `Django` application integrated with `MongoDB`, particularly when dealing with high traffic and concurrent users. Despite using `update_one` with `upsert`, I'm observing instances where double (at times tripple) records are being created intermittently under these conditions.

Below is a simplified example of the code snippet I'm using:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from django.conf import settings


# MongoDB connection setup
client = MongoClient(settings.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL)
db = client[settings.DATABASE_NAME]
collection = db[settings.COLLECTION_NAME]


class UserDataView(APIView):
    def post(self, request) -> Response:
        try:
            # Using update_one with upsert to handle user data updates
            collection.update_one(
                {'user_id': request.user.pk},
                {'$set': {'data': request.data["data"]}},
                upsert=True
            )
            
            # Returning a successful response with a data-related message
            return Response(
                {'message': 'User data successfully updated or created'},
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK
            )
        except KeyError as e:
            # Logging and handling potential errors
            logger.error(e)
            
            # Returning a response for a bad request with a data-related message
            return Response(
                {'message': 'Bad request. Please provide the required data'},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            )
```

Even with the `upsert=True` option, duplicate records are created sporadically, and this seems to happen during periods of high traffic and concurrent user activity.

I've ensured that the `user_id`  is correctly set as the unique identifier, and there are no apparent errors in the MongoDB logs. This behavior is challenging to reproduce, making it difficult to identify the root cause.

Are there any considerations or best practices I should be aware of when using `update_one` with `upsert` in scenarios with high traffic and concurrent users? Any insights on how to address or troubleshoot this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: "_I've ensured that the user_id  is correctly set as the unique identifier_" - does this correspond with a unique index in the database? If not, you'll need to create one. If so, that (creation of duplicate documents violating a unique index that is present) sounds like a serious issue that you should raise with the vendor

Comment: @user20042973 yes user_id was set as a unique index in the database. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: But is the index _currently_ there and defined correctly? It would be very helpful to see output from a shell session where you `.getIndexes()` and then subsequently do a `.find(...)` on the same collection showing duplicates. The [official documentation for `upsert`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-with-unique-index) talks about the expected behavior here, so double check that everything is configured as intended first

Comment: Sure. Thanks man. I’ll go through the doc